# MVVM pattern - is it okay to put UI related data in the model?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

ATM I'm trying to get the hang of MVVM, databinding and commands. I'm trying to (re)create a [game menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNClJ.jpg) using the pattern. I've got a couple of questions.

1) Right now I have the button content (Party Paradigms etc) in the model of the application and binding to it from my UI buttons. But since this is more of a UI sort of thing, I was wondering if this was the correct way to handle things.

My thoughts were that it'd be easier since I would just change the properties whenever I went into a submenu (e.g. datalog) and the button content would change automatically.
How would you handle it?

2) The label next to the clock icon is supposed to be a counter. Again, would you put this kind of logic in the VM or the xaml.cs file?

Also I got some problems with the StopWatch and the INotifyPropertyChanged interface. Right now I have the Stopwatch method in my xaml.cs file:

```
MainMenuVM mvm = new MainMenuVM();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = mvm;
        Thread thread = new Thread(StopWatch);
        thread.Start();
    }

    public void StopWatch()
    {
        int secs = 0, mins = 0, hours = 0;

        while (true)
        {
            secs++;
            if (secs == 60)
            {
                mins++;
                secs = 0;
            }

            if (mins == 60)
            {
                hours++;
                mins = 0;
            }

            if (mins >= 10 && secs < 10)
            {
                mvm.Stopwatch = "0" + hours + ":" + mins + ":" + "0" + secs;
            }

            if (mins >= 10 && secs >= 10)
            {
                mvm.Stopwatch = "0" + hours + ":" + mins + ":" + secs;
            }

            if (mins < 10 && secs >= 10)
            {
                mvm.Stopwatch = "0" + hours + ":" + "0" + mins + ":" + secs;
            }

            if (mins < 10 && secs < 10)
            {
                mvm.Stopwatch = "0" + hours + ":" + "0" + mins + ":" + "0" + secs;
            }

            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
```

And I have my Time-label content bound to the mvm.Stopwatch property.

```
<Label x:Name="lblTime" Content="{Binding Stopwatch}" />
```

Stopwatch property:

```
public string Stopwatch
    {
        get
        {
            if (_stopwatch == null)
            {
                _stopwatch = "00:00:00";
            }
            return _stopwatch;
        }
        set { _stopwatch = value; YouChanged("Stopwatch"); // Calling the INotify event
        }
    }
```

But for some reason I get a good old 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' whenever I reach the stopwatch setter and call the event.

Comment: I think the `YouChanged` method is where your null reference is happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a simple concept,

- Keep the Model as dumb as possible. Try to keep it re-usable to your best extents.

Point **"1"**

No I personally would not have `Button` `Content` coming from the Model. Your Button's content from what you explained has nothing to do with the back-end logic or functionality. Say if the same `Content` was for a `TextBlock` or so where the label indicated a "User Name" in a messenger app, then it would make sense for the Model to hold that data. Here it's just you re-using a ui control in the View.

Solution:

I'd probably just have separate Button's and set one to collapsed when needed. That way I'm not making the `Command` that the button corresponds to perform different actions based on it's content or something else magically. If you insist on using one button then maybe store the string's in a Resource file and use Bindings to bind to them from the View(Helps with localisation too if needed).

Point **"2"**

In the VM. This is logic tied into functionality and should be "testable" with unit-tests for app behavior.

Just ask yourself, is this logic that I should probably be testing for and if it is so it cannot be in the View. If your not able to get it off the View, then your probably doing stuff wrong in MVVM)

Point **"3"**

Do not have logic that's not just View related in the View. So if you have animation code or stuff that purely is visual enhancements then use code-behind, else stay off it cos it just hurts you.

Firstly I have to say that Stopwatch implementation is rather poor(no offense) you can and should probably make it decent.

[Simple StopWatch Example](http://miteshsureja.blogspot.co.uk/2012/01/how-to-create-stop-watch-application-in.html) - Have a look through it and check the usage of string Format
 with a `DispatcherTimer`. You can supply string Formats directly in xaml making it even cleaner since your back-end can just hold the actual data.

For your PropertyChanged null error. Are you checking if it's null in the function? If your new to MVVM start off with a helper library like [MVVM Light](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/). Even if you want to do everything yourself, Use it to teach yourself what they do and why they do it.

Comment: Great, thank you for the answer. Cleared up a few things! I knew the stopwatch was less fortunate, but it works! (well, worked..)

Answer (score 3):

It's normal to have view-related data (colors, visibility, labels, etc) in the view model.  Remember, in MVVM there's a "model" and a "view model", so the latter is actually supposed to have properties for the view.

As far as the "object reference not set", I'm guessing you need to check if `PropertyChanged` is null (in the `YouChanged` method), which happens if no one is actually subscribed to the event:

```
public void YouChanged(string propName)
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        PropertyChanged(propName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. So if I wanted to change the background of my application, I'd store the property for this in my viewmodel? Seems like that would be a lot of properties...

Comment: @user2309266 only if it's variable, right?  If it's fixed, you'd of course just put it in the XAML.

Comment: Yeah, only if it's a variable :) I am asking because my plan was to change the background in every submenu. Also - how do you normally change datacontext?

Comment: Right, a lightbulb just went on :) I think I got it. Again, thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The only possible answer is surely "It depends...", although I think in 99% of cases the answer is no.  To illustrate the roles of the different layers in MVVM let us consider a game of [Tic-Tac-Toe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tic-tac-toe).

**Model: A UI-technology agnostic model of the domain**

In a MVVM implementation of Tic-Tac-Toe, the model contains the objects and interactions that define the game of Tic-Tac-Toe. (e.g. Player, Game objects and methods that represent someone taking a turn.) The important thing is that even if you never plan to use the model outside of the current application, there should be no coupling of the model to the fact you are using WPF (say).  Why?  Because there is nothing about playing Tic-Tac-Toe specific to WPF.  I could play it on a piece of paper if I wish and the basic objects and their interactions would still be the same.

**View Model: A logical representation of the UI**

The View Model is essentially the logical representation of the UI.  If my particular UI for Tic-Tac-Toe has a "Reset" button, there should be an appropriate command on the View Model. Personally, I would attempt to keep the View-Model as free of UI-related objects as possible and try to make the interface expose the *functionality* of playing the game, rather than any aesthetic properties.

If I want the background of the application to change depending on whether it is the turn of player 1 or player 2, I would have a property on my View-Model called "ActivePlayer", and then user a converter or data trigger (if using WPF) to convert this value to the appropriate background colour.  This way all the volatility around what the UI looks like is kept in the View layer. (I consider converters to be part of the View).

**View: Aesthetic Logic**

I've already implicitly alluded to the fact that the View is where you concentrate on aesthetic logic.  This includes specific references to colours, animations, whether certain elements are visible and the layout.

What about the 1%? I said at the beginning that putting UI-related data is a no-no 99% of the time.  However, if my application is modelling something that is a UI concept (say a colour picker), then it is only natural that my model would have a notion of colour.  Having said that, even then I would try to keep it UI-technology agnostic by storing colours as AGRB values instead of one of the various .NET classes representing colour.